# Big theta for a S(n)

Tags: asymptotics

Consider the following function:
$$S(n)=1+c+c^2+⋅⋅⋅+c^n,$$
where c is a positive real number.

(A) This function is the sum of a geometric series. Give a precise closed-form formula for S(n), interms of c and n, in the case where c≠1.

which is $S(n)=\frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1}$

(B) Show that S(n) is:

θ(1) if c<1

θ(n) if c=1

---

im having problems solving these two big theta problems can someone give me a nudge in the right direction (i know how big theta is defined), so i assume that i need to find two constants for which the function is bounded, but how do i go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First,
if $c=1$,
$S(n)$ should be pretty obvious.

Second,
if $c < 1$,
write the formula in the form
$S(n) = \dfrac{1-c^{n+1}}{1-c}$
and show that
$S(n) > 1$
and
$S(n) < \dfrac1{1-c}$.

Comment: ok but how did you know to compare S(n) to those two constants (how did you know what constants to use)?